# call stored procedure with linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

i am try to call stored procedure like this:

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter("d", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param1.Value = d;
var param2 = new SqlParameter("c", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param2.Value = c;
var param3 = new SqlParameter("b", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param3.Value = b;
var param4 = new SqlParameter("a", SqlDbType.BigInt);
param4.Value = a;


((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("schema.stored_name", param1, param2, param3, param4);
```

but throw Procedure or function 'stored_name' expects parameter '@d', which was not supplied.

also i created array an set values but dosent work, any idea????

Comment: I think you have to actually call the parameter "@d"?

Comment: Ya "@" is missing with the parameter names a, b, c, d. Try prefixing @

Comment: I already tried and that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

You may try stating the parameter names in the command text :

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext
   .ExecuteStoreCommand("schema.stored_name @d, @c, @b, @a", param1, param2, param3, param4);
```